# How do you convert from CCITT Group 4 to JBIG/JBIG2?

Tags: libtiff.net

Would it be possible for someone to point me to the general direction on how to convert from CCITT Group4 to JBIG and/or JBIG2 compression? This would be for either single page and multi page tiffs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further research into the source code it is not possible with libtiff.net as the compression type JBIG is only a placeholder in the library and the codec is not actually implemented. For those looking for an answer to this I ended up using the Jbig2Enc from the following links...

Blog with a compiled exe wrapper for the Jbig2enc and a python script to convert the output of the Jbig2enc to pdf. 
http://soft.rubypdf.com/software/windows-version-jbig2-encoder-jbig2-exe

More Information on how to call the Jbig2.exe and pdf.py python script.
http://blog.rubypdf.com/2009/10/29/convert-jbig2-to-pdf-with-free-and-open-source-software-agls-jbig2enc/

jbig2enc c/c++ library by Adam Langley
https://github.com/agl/jbig2enc